# Why does using .next() select all li items instead of just one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I'm having an issue using jQuery `.next()` on my `ul`. What I will is for when the user clicks the next button it only adds it to `li` next to it. For some reason it keeps adding it to every list item.  Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JLSR3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.next').click(function(){
        //alert('clicked');
        $('ul.menu li').next().addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: you selected all list items, then selected the next list item, which will be all list items other than the first one. your logic/selector is flawed.

Comment: "...next to it" Next to what???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `$('ul.menu li')` will select all your list items within `ul.menu`; `.next()` will then find the next element for each and every element in `$('ul.menu li')`, and hence you're dealing with several elements when you add your class.

I think you probably want to start with having the active class on one of the `li` elements, and then use something like:

```
$('ul.menu li.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because your selector is too generic.

```
$('ul.menu li') //--> will return all li's of the menu
.next() //--> will return all the next li's to the selected li's
```

You can to instead add active to the first `li` to start with and on click of next select `next` to `$('ul.menu li:active')` removing the current active one. And do the same for previous.

You could do:

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>

<a class="traverse" data-action="prev" href="#">previous</a>
<a class="traverse" data-action="next" href="#">next</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var  $menu = $('ul.menu'), 
        $menus =  $menu.children('li');

    $('a.traverse').click(function(){
        var action = $(this).data('action'), //Get the action prev/next
            jump = (action === 'next' ? 'first' : 'last'), //based on action determine the jump to switch to first or last when reached the end to enable a cycle
            $active = $menus.filter('.active').removeClass('active'), //remove current active li's class
            $target = $active[action](); //get the target applying the action

         if ( $target.length === 0){ //If no target i.e when it is at first or last and clicking on prev or next reptly
               $target =  $menus[jump](); //get the next element using the jump
         } 

        $target.addClass('active'); //add class to the target
    });
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9xC6u/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the nextElement

```
var currentLi = $('.menu li').first();
$('a.next').click(function(){   
    if(!currentLi.hasClass('active')) {
        currentLi.addClass('active');
    } else {
        currentLi.removeClass('active');
        currentLi = currentLi.next();
        currentLi.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I forked your jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hatemalimam/8nqxt/